# Reading list for mathematics and formal logic with missing truth values?

Tags: formal-languages, logic, mathematical-foundations

I would like a reading list of math and formal logic books which give a principled discussion of missing values.

Textbooks on mathematics and formal logic - propositional and first-order and higher-order - are very clear and helpful.

Different programming languages make their own choices about how to handle missing values. For example, in the R language, a truth-table for OR, the mathematical max and order translate to:

```r
x <- c(NA, FALSE, TRUE)
names(x) <- as.character(x)
outer(x, x, "|") ## OR  table
#>       <NA> FALSE TRUE
#> <NA>    NA    NA TRUE
#> FALSE   NA FALSE TRUE
#> TRUE  TRUE  TRUE TRUE

max(c(NA, 1, 3))
#> [1] NA

sort(c(1, 2, NA, 3))
#> [1] 1 2 3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

But how timeless or general are the choices made by any one programming language?

Comment: You can start with [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic). The most popular semantics is Kleene logic. See also recent work on hazard-free circuits, e.g. [this article](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3320123).

Comment: Thank you @YuvalFilmus. I will start reading on those lines.